# How to override !important background-image gradient using javascript

Tags: background-image, gradient

I'm building a jquery mobile app, and in my theme roller file I've assigned a color to my buttons (say blue). Now, there are certain buttons in my app that I've addded this css line to:

```
.navButton {
background-image: linear-gradient( 0, #333333, #424242, #515151) !important;
```

This works fine. The problem is that I'd like to change this gradient on certain js events. So I've tried adding this next line to my js, but it doesn't work (unless I remove the css line above, then it has no problem overriding the themeroller default):

```
$("[name=serviceButton]").css('background-image', 'linear-gradient( 0, #333333, #222222, #515151 )');
```

Is there a way to add "!important" in the js line? Will this override the css !important, or does that depend on which one the app reads first..?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove '!important' from .navButton

when you use jquery.css(), it actually add a style attribute to the dom(style="background-image:xxx")

typically the style attribute has the higher priority than .navButton, but '!important' is an exception and it has the highest priority.

And maybe add '!important' in jquery.css() will work, I'm not sure for that.

Comment: Removing the !important from the css file (inside the .navButton) will cause it to not override the theme-roller file. So the button ignores the background-image gradient and remains blue...
But it's good to know that the style attribute has higher priority than the class callout. :) Thanks!